# What is the most efficient way to toggle between two components React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I have seen multiple examples on how to toggle a single component's visibility but what would be the most efficient way to toggle between the visibility of two sibling components in React?

Comment: I would use what I use for a single component... { toggle && <component 1> } { !toggle && <component 2> }, but there are other ways, using a ternary operator, or if statement. No big difference in efficiency, so readabilty is impottant, too.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What's your case? *I have seen multiple examples on how to toggle a single component's visibility* - what are they and what did you try? There are no 'best' or 'most efficient' ways.

Answer (score 3):

I typically use a separate function with some logic to decide what to display, and place that function within the main render function.  Take the code below for example:

```js
const FirstComponent = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div className='first-class'>Hello, I am the first component!</div>
  )
}

const SecondComponent = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div className='second-class'>And I am the second component!</div>
  )
}

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      display: 'first'
    };
  }
  
  changeDisplay = () => {
    let { display } = this.state;
    this.setState({ display: display === 'first' ? 'second' : 'first' });
  }
  
  renderInner() {
    let { display } = this.state;
    
    if (display === 'first') {
      return <FirstComponent />
    } else if (display === 'second') {
      return <SecondComponent />
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div className='main-class'>
        <div className='button' onClick={this.changeDisplay}>Click me</div>
        {this.renderInner()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const root = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, root);
```

```css
.first-class {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.second-class {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-class {
  margin-top: 10px
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: Let me clarify that this is for scenarios in which the logic behind the display is more advanced (even though my example was very simple).  If the toggle is a simple boolean, the best approach is definitely: {toggle ? <Comp1 /> : <Comp2 />}

Answer (score 1):

```
{toggle?<Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
```

Seems to be the most readable approach. This is common to see this to display a fake component while loading a component:

```
 {loaded?<Component /> : <Loading />}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched the library in a while, but I'm pretty sure the best way is:

1. Obviously have a parent component of both
2. Each child component should have [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) implemented in such a way that a re-render will only trigger when it actual require an update.

This way, you can switch both of them without worrying about unnecessary renders